# How to disable ssl certificate verification in react-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, ssl

I am building an app in react-native. I am trying to hit an API in react-native using fetch method. The SSL certificate verification when turned off gives a response from API otherwise "no response" is shown. Is there a way to disable SSL certificate verification in react-native?
Below is my code snippet for hitting API .

```
fetch(('https:www.myUrl.com',{
       method: 'GET',
       headers:{
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       },
}))
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson))
     })
     .catch((err) => {
          Alert.alert("Request Failed")
          console.log(err.toString())
     });
```

Comment: "Is there a way to disable SSL certificate verification in react-native?" Not a good idea, you lose almost all benefits of HTTPS. You might as well do clear text HTTP instead...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have tried it ,it isn't working